# Probook 4520s CPU hangs at 100% and 199MHz? any ideas

Tags: cpu, utilization

This issue is always resolved after a restart, but happens randomly.

I tried adjusting minimum processor power state from power management, however issue still persists.

Answer (score 0):

Check how many processes you have running. Make sure you are seeing the system processes as well. Arrange them by CPU, and then end any of them that you can.

SOURCE: This has worked for me!!